# What is wrong with my code, I have tried many ways, but I keep on getting this: TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: google-colaboratory

What is wrong with my code?? I have tried multiple times different ways, but apparently I keep on getting the same answer. What my objective is is to ask the user to pick a number and then python will portray a multiplication table until that number. So if it was until 9, it would create something like this:

```
1|    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9     
2|    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   
3|    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   
4|    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36     
5|    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   
6|    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   
7|    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63    
8|    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   
9|    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81
```

But, I want to ***prompt*** the user first. My code is below:

```
    h=input('Pick a number:')
print("     ", end="")
for i in range (1,str('h'+1)):
  print("%5d"%i, end="")

print()
print("_______"*12)

for i in range(1,str(h+1)):
  print("%5d|"%i, end="")

  for j in range(1,int(h+1)):
    print("%5d"%(i*j), end="")
  
  print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
str(h+1)
```

To

```
int(h)+1
```

Comment: Ok, would that help with functions? Like, is that helping me refactor my program into a function?